# Active Directory & Windows phone 7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, active-directory

I'm developping an application, where the users can connect via Active Directory.
I searched but apparently i have to use a web service. 
It is not a problem, because in the futur users from differents active directory will use this application (If the list of domain is on the webservice, i will not have to update the windows phone application) 
So i have to implement a generic way, to connect with Active Directory via a WCF.
It is possible to implement a generic way to use Active Directory on a WCF?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible and seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about user authentication, you might want to read these two articles:

- [Authentication, Authorization, and Identities in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx)
- [Using Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 in Identity Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335705.aspx)